# Repeat title slide at end of reveal.js presentation

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I'd like to repeat my title slide at the end of my quarto reveal.js presentation.

I'm looking for a command like `title-slide` or something other.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the exact same title slide at the end of the presentations?

Comment: Yes, as we can do in beamer with this code : 

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible to do this in revealjs too using javascript and revealjs api but it would not be as easy as the case of beamer!

Comment: I was hoping an easy way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in the comment, you can make use of some javascript code and CSS to automatically repeat your title slide at the end of the presentation.

Attach the following **`append-title-slide.html`** file in the presentation using the `include-in-header` YAML key in quarto.

**append-title-slide.html**

```html
<script>
  function move_titleSlide() {
      var titleSlide = document.querySelector('section#title-slide');
      var titleSlideClone = titleSlide.cloneNode(true);
      titleSlideClone.id = 'title-slide-cloned';
      document.querySelector('.reveal .slides').appendChild(titleSlideClone);
      Reveal.sync();
  }

  window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    move_titleSlide();
  });
</script>


<style>
  #title-slide-cloned {
    text-align: center
  }

  #title-slide-cloned .subtitle {
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem
  }
</style>
```

**presentation.qmd**

````markdown
---
title: "Title Slide"
subtitle: "Its a subtitle"
author: None
date: last-modified
format: 
  revealjs:
    include-in-header: append-title-slide.html
slide-number: true
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished presentation. To learn more about Quarto presentations see <https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/>.

## Bullets

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes:

-   Content authored with markdown
-   Output from executable code

## Code

When you click the **Render** button a presentation will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

Comment: Hello ! Thanks a lot for this perfectly functionnal answer ! Is it possible to add a call for these slide, because I'd like finally to put this slide and after some additional uncounted slides like [this](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#slide-visibility)

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a call" for slides?

Comment: I'd like to "call" my title slide, like in Beamer (# titlepage for example), and add after ## additionnal slide {visibility="uncounted"}. These additionnal slides are as appendix

Comment: Oh, I get it. But you should have said all of these in your question at the very first (like "I want to repeat my title slide again and then add some uncounted slides after that title slide"). But now **though my answer answers perfectly your question in title, it will not be useful to you** : )

Comment: So here's what I would suggest. At first, accept this answer since it does answer your initial question and then post another question with those additional questions you have!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm sorry. I've already tried to vote your answer yesterday, but I'm not 15 reputation so I can't cast a vote. I'm trying to make your suggestion, this reputation score would increase ! It's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76261113/repeat-title-slide-at-end-of-reveal-js-presentation-and-add-additionnal-slides-a)